# Is it more resource intensive to include/require a php file than an html file?

Tags: php, include, require

I was wondering about this. I have the habit of naming my files `*.php` when including them, even though I don't require any PHP executions. Does this have any negative consequences on server load? I.e. does the server need more time to parse a PHP file than an HTML file? (I would guess so, because the server would just "import" an HTML file, but a PHP should first be read to be sure it doesn't contain any PHP commands itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think the performance difference is noticeable. Keep in mind PHP is designed to be integrated with HTML easily. This means the PHP engine will only ever active when it encounters the PHP opening and closing tags `<?php ?>`. Therefore pure HTML is just included and nothing else is done.

The only side effect I can see is that making all your files `.php` can make your work figuring which file contains PHP a little harder. I personally use `.html` for pure HTML files, `.phtml` for files with both PHP and HTML and `.php` for pure PHP.

Answer (score 1):

It's not very clear from the question but I assume you are talking about PHP code that does:

```
include 'file1.php';
```

vs.

```
include 'file2.html';
```

when both `file1.php` and `file2.html` contain only HTML content and no PHP blocks (`<?php ... ?>`).

The answer is very simple: you may name the files you include whatever way you prefer, **there is no difference on the way they are parsed**.

The included files are parsed at runtime. When the interpreter reaches an `include` statement it acts as if the current PHP block ends, it loads, parses and runs the included file then it starts a new PHP block. In short, an `include` is, more or less, the same as:

```
... code before 'include'
?>
... paste the content of the included file (file1.php or file2.html)
<?php
... code after 'include'
```

It doesn't matter at all what is the name of the included file and what is its termination. It can be `.html`, `.php` it can be even `.c` or `.exe` or it could have no termination at all. The PHP interpreter treats all of them the same. Only the content  of the included file matters.

The answer to your question is: **No, it isn't more resource intensive; it isn't less intensive either. It is just the same.**

Answer (score 0):

No, It doesn't have any side effects on server.